# Connection issue when connect from outside to Pilot

Tags: istio

We have an issue while connecting from outside to pilot.
After a while the connection is closed and not restored.
When we restart the ingress, the connection works fine.
I suspect the issue with the Istio ingress, checked the CDS/LDS/EDS/RDS/STIOD.

My Istio version: `1.10.3`.

`istioctl proxy-status:`

```
NAME                                               CDS    LDS    EDS    RDS      ISTIOD                  VERSION
istio-egressgateway-78d75d8868-95znd.istio-system  SYNCED SYNCED SYNCED NOT SENT istiod-7b7587d6fd-6rtf8 1.10.3
istio-ingressgateway-5c5499b774-kfz49.istio-system SYNCED SYNCED SYNCED SYNCED   istiod-7b7587d6fd-6rtf8 1.10.3
```

What should be checked/changed to solve it?

Comment: How did you setup your cluster - some bare-metal solution or cloud provider? Which Kubernetes version are you using? Which [installation configuration profile](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/config-profiles/) did you use? Could you share logs from the Istio ingress gateway pod when connection is not working (get pod name using `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` command and then `kubectl logs istio-ingressgateway-{some-random} -n istio-system`)? How do you connecting from the outside to the pilot?

Comment: Hi,  a bare-meta solution , K8S version is v1.20.5 , Pls see logs :rt is closing
2021-12-03T18:00:57.007064Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2021-12-03T18:32:09.366081Z     warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, transport is closing
2021-12-03T18:32:09.454788Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
2021-12-03T19:02:23.902844Z     warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, transport is closing

Comment: in addition to previous comment, "How do you connecting from the outside to the pilot? - the connection is to istio ingress gateway  is via IP address that istio holds and  that have dns record of some server  we trying to reach

Comment: note: we using the IPV6 and not IPV4, we dont have an option to debug the istioctl pls see the similar error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a6eZ6ldF2l7De3vX-SBAHmuJ00uxlgpPznHocG7zcfs/edit

Comment: Which bare-metal solution did you use? How did you setup your cluster for IPv6 - it it [dual stack or IPv6 only](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dual-stack/)? The document you sent, points that there is different behaviour for each container runtime, which one are you using - Docker or containerd? Please make [your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by adding steps / tutorials that you used for setting Kubernetes, Istio and IPv6.

Comment: Hi, we are using HP proliant 360 GEN9 with Centos 7.9 OS  , for container runtime we using Docker and using IPV6 only.

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes to your cluster - kubespray, kubeadm or some other solution? Kubernetes on CentOS can tricky because of the firewalld, did you configure / change settings of the firewall in your CentOS system? After the connection is closed, are you able to ping your server? Which Load Balancer solution are you using for your bare-metal cluster?

Comment: Hi @Wytrzymały Wiktor we use Robin.io over K8s, so the installation was via robin.io , firewalld - is disabled on machines. we use Metal LB for bare-metal cluster. when ping the reply is Time exceeded: Hop limit

Comment: Hi @Mikolaj S , i added another reply , pls see above

Comment: Hmm this message (Time exceeded: Hop limit) looks like a problem with a network. How exactly are you restarting ingress?

Comment: Also, when connection is down, could you please find the node on which there is a pod istio-ingressgateway-{...} (command: `kubectl -n istio-system get pods -o wide`) ? Please also note the IP address of the pod. Then please SSH into this node and run `curl -I {IP-address-of the-pod}:15021/healthz/ready` and check if it is working (return code `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`)?